# SOLR installation on Websphere Portal

Tags: solr, websphere-portal

I try to install SOLR 3.6.0  on a Websphere Portal 7.0. It gives me the following messages in the log:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.open(Ljava/io/File;)Lorg/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory;
    at org.apache.solr.core.StandardDirectoryFactory.open(StandardDirectoryFactory.java:33&#41

After some research I found some lucene which comes with the Portal server.
This is the place, where it's found:
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/prereq/prereq.lucene/shared/app/lucene.jar.

I suspect that this messed up the classloader. I have changed the classloader policy of the application  :(

Have anyone experienced the same and did you find a work around?

Thats in advance for your answers

Cheers,

-Fred